# How do I include a column in codeigniter query that isn't actually in the database?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

We can achieve this in sql.

```html
$this->db->select('mytype as type');
```

```
{select 'mytype' as type from mytype}
```

How to achieve this in codeigniter?
I tried

```
{$this->db->select('mytype as type');}
```

Comment: Hey Prashant! I'm not sure I understand. What you tried and what can achieve are the same thing: `$this->db->select('mytype as type');` How can both not do the same thing? Also, are you sure that code snippet is necessary? what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$this->db->select('"mytype" as type', FALSE);
```

OR

```
$this->db->select('mytype as type', FALSE);
```